# Hadoop Archive Command

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-archive

How to use Hadoop archive technique and the command needed?

Answer (score 0):

To create a hadoop archive:

```
hadoop archive -archiveName name -p <parent> <src>* <dest>
```

Refer: [Hadoop Archives Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hadoop_archives.html)